# What is the name of a variable $v\in V$ in a grammar $G=(V,T,P,S)$ s.t $v\Longrightarrow_{G}^{*}\epsilon$?

Tags: terminology, formal-languages, formal-grammar

I have a variable $v\in V$ in a grammar $G=(V,T,P,S)$ s.t $$v\Longrightarrow_{G}^{*}\epsilon$$

Where $\epsilon$ is the empty string.

Is there a name for such a variable $v$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen it called "nullable" (in "Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation" by Hopcroft, Motwani, Ullman)